# Pass in an object before its declared inside another object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am currently finding myself in situations where I must pass in an object before its declared inside another object. How exactly do I do this? Below is an example. The two objects work together but I cant figure out how to pass something that doesnt even exist yet.

```
class fooBar() {
    this.alpha = new alpha(this.beta);
    this.beta = new beta(this.alpha);
}

class alpha {
    constructor(beta) {
        this.beta = beta;
    }

    getName() {
        return "alpha";
    }
}

class beta {
    constructor(alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }

    getName() {
        return "beta";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's called a circular dependency. Don't do that.

Comment: What are some strategies to fix that?

Comment: @J.Titus some sort of bridge class maybe?

Comment: You can't pass something that doesn't exist. You can create two objects independently and *then* set a property in one that refers to the other. Or have one object create the other. (I don't think there's anything wrong with having circular dependencies as long as you've thought it through.)

Comment: @nnnnnn so I definately need some interface and think it through before doing it like this right?

Comment: I can't really say if you "definitely" need something because I don't know what underlying problem you're trying to solve. But you should think through any data structures before getting too far into the project because it would be painful to refactor them later.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set them later. For example:

```
class fooBar() {
    this.alpha = new alpha();
    this.beta = new beta();

    this.alpha.setBeta(this.beta);
    this.beta.setAlpha(this.alpha);
}

class alpha {
    constructor(beta) {
        if(beta) {
          this.beta = beta;
        }
    }

    getName() {
        return "alpha";
    }

    setBeta(beta) {
        this.beta = beta;
    }
}

class beta {
    constructor(alpha) {
        if(alpha) {
          this.alpha = alpha;
        }
    }

    getName() {
        return "beta";
    }

    setAlpha(alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }
}
```

You don't have to call them by those method names, but the idea is just to wait until after you invoke each constructor to set some property.

Comment: So is this a circular dependency?

Comment: @Asperger, yep, this is a circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(beta) {

    this.beta = beta;
    if(!this.beta){
         var that=this;
        let jobBeta=setInterval(()=>{
              if(beta || beta ===0){
                       that.beta=beta;
                        clearInterval(jobBeta);
                }

          },1)
    }
}
```

The same thing to be done for `alpha` in the other class (vice-versa)